# Setting up BIND9 on Debain

Tags: debian, dns, vps, bind

So I've got a VPS, and registered a domain name and I want to have the domain point to the VPS.

I have installed and configured BIND9 (on the VPS that the domain should point to). If I ping my domain from that VPS, it all works as expected and I get a response back (from itself).

**EDIT: This only seems to work when I ping ns1.mydomain.com.au, not just mydomain.com.au - why would this be?**

Trouble is, the Internet doesn't appear to have learned about this change and if I ping the domain from any other server or computer, I just get host not found or something.

Is there something I need to configure to get the DNS records to spread over the Internet?

Cheers

Comment: Your domain registrar has to list your vm's IP as the authoritative source of the domain name.

Comment: This is what I thought, but I contacted them and they said I had the option to either install my own DNS server or buy one from them... I guess I'll get back in contact and tell them I have my own, so they should do what you said?

Comment: Yes. A domain name must point at some IP (DNS server). You don't need to buy a DNS server from them because you have it. So all you need is for them to forward all requests for your domain name to your VM's IP.